# Create New row using bootstrap widgets TbSelect2

Tags: yii, yii-booster

Hello I am using bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2 in Yii.
You can see this link to check my form.
https://www.diigo.com/item/p/qoaqepdzbsbbaqeqdzbcbrsdpa/bc91ebd999371bef68737b8320afed91

How to add the data in TbSelect2?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

its so simple , just generate an array for this

```
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
            'asDropDownList' => true,
            'name'           => 'status',
            'data'           => array( // свои значения для option
                'active'  => 'Active',
                'pending' => 'Pending',
                'invited' => 'Invited',
                'deleted' => 'Deleted'
            ),

        )

);
```

Comment: hi @klamoz, what is that events? did I need to use an ajax? for that? I just want to add the data from TbSelect to database ..